# How to reference scala Enumeration from other package

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I'm having trouble understanding why I can't reference a scala enum type.

The problem is that sometimes I can reference enums:

```
enum(UserStatus)
```

and sometimes it complains about not being able to find the enum

```
not found: type UserStatus
```

How come I sometimes cannot reference the Enumeration class?

The generated source for the enum seems to be ok, and it works great with another enum that I have which lives in the same place, same usage...

Any Suggestions?

## More info

The generated source for the enum is:

```
public final class models.UserStatus extends java.lang.Object{
    public static final scala.Enumeration$Value Busy();
    public static final scala.Enumeration$Value Free();
    public static final scala.Enumeration$ValueSet$ ValueSet();
    public static final scala.Enumeration$Value withName(java.lang.String);
    public static final scala.Enumeration$Value apply(int);
    public static final int maxId();
    public static final scala.Enumeration$ValueSet values();
    public static final java.lang.String toString();
}
```

I'm trying to implement an enum mapper for play framework 2.0

```
def enumFormat[E <: Enumeration](enum: E): Formatter[E#Value] = new Formatter[E#Value] {
  def bind(key: String, data: Map[String, String]) = {
    Formats.stringFormat.bind(key, data).right.flatMap { s =>
      scala.util.control.Exception.allCatch[E#Value]
        .either(enum.withName(s))
        .left.map(e => Seq(FormError(key, "error.enum", Nil)))
    }
  }
  def unbind(key: String, value: E#Value) = Map(key -> value.toString)
}
```

And this method that calls the mapper

```
def enum[E <: Enumeration](enum: E): Mapping[E#Value] = of(enumFormat(enum))
```

This means that the mapper automatically converts between a enum when using the form binding

Pseudo code of usage.

```
package models {
  object UserStatus extends Enumeration {
    val Free = Value("free")
    val Busy = Value("busy")
  }

  case class User(
    status: UserStatus.Value = UserStatus.Free
  )
}

package controllers {
  imports models._
  val userForm = Form(
    mapping(
      "status" -> enum(UserStatus)
    )(User.apply)(User.unapply)
  )
}
```

Comment: I tried it out, works like a charm... cool solution :)

Comment: I'm trying to get it pulled into core. but I wan't to be shure that the Enumerations work as they should. Tell me if your having any problems with referencing the Enum in the controller. that's where the compiler is giving me a hard time.

Comment: `import models._` should pull everything into scope. The only thing I added was `type UserStatus = Value` (but I'm not sure it was necessary). Can you put your code on Github? So far I see no problems with it.

Comment: Here it is: https://github.com/playframework/Play20/pull/240 though this is only the implementation. I'll see if I can put together an example

Comment: Yes that's how I did it when trying out your code. It's a really good contribution, bravo!

Comment: I wouldn't bother with `scala.Enumeration`, it is beyond broken. Simply use Java enums.

Comment: I'm confused as to how the accepted answer solves the OP. It just provides a generic Scala solution for enum types and it doesn't solve the issue of supplying an enum type to the Scala-Play Form apply ... am I missing anything??

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your problem may come from the fact that in Scala you can use the same *identifier* for a *type* and for a *value*.

When you write the following:

```scala
object Foo extends Enumeration {
  val A, B, C = Value
}
```

You define a `Foo` **object**, but you don’t define a `Foo` **type**. If you come from a Java background you may *not* find this behavior intuitive.

So what’s the type of the `Foo` enumeration values? Their type is `Foo.Value` (that’s called a *path dependent type*).

If you want to define a `Foo` type corresponding to the enumeration values type, you can alias the `Foo.Value` type:

```scala
object Foo extends Enumeration {
  type Foo = Value    // Type alias
  val A, B, C = Value
}
```

Now you can refer to the enumeration type by writing `Foo.Foo`. You can import the fields of the `Foo` object to reduce the syntactic overhead:

```scala
import Foo._
def bar(foo: Foo): String = foo match {
  case A => "value A"
  case B => "value B"
  case C => "value C"
}
```

In the above code, the first line refers to the `Foo` *object*, and the second line refers to the `Foo` *type*.

Comment: I am confused as to how this answer solves the OP. You are giving a solution Scala generic for enum types and it doesn't solve the issue of supplying an enum type to the Scala-Play Form apply ... am I missing anything??